# How will the DAML Code affecting two distinct DA Nodes be deployed and how will its integrity maintained?

Tags: daml

I am looking for DA’s recommendation/best practices regarding writing and deploying DAML code and object (.daml and .dar) in production grade solutions.
Let us take a scenario - Central Authority (CA) operating node may issue a new role under a contract to Participant 1 (P1) by writing a simple DAML code, below are few questions related to the DAML deployment –

a.  Assuming DAML code will be written by CA, can we say that only CA needs to have this code and its build on its node and CA will simply execute the contract workflow allowing Party on P1 Node to simply accept/reject the role without having to know the content of the DAML code (business logic and other contract templates) written by CA ?

b.  Will the DAML code file (.daml) written by CA Node needs to be transmitted to Participant 1 (P1) node so that P1 can verify and agree with the DAML file code (contract templates, parties and choices) and put the code and its build (.dar) into its node as well?

c.  If the answer to above question is yes, how will the integrity of the DAML code be maintained e.g. what if DAML code is changed by P1 or CA at the time of deployment, which may cause conflict later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contract model, in the form of a `dar` file has to be supplied to all nodes that participate in the workflows modeled in that `dar` file.
A `dar` file can contain multiple DAML "packages" and each package is identified by its name and a hash.
On ledger, contract types (called `template`) are fully qualified, including package hash. If you change your templates, the package hash changes and thus the new templates are seen as completely different from the old ones by the ledger.
To change an existing contract model, you have to upgrade existing contracts using a DAML workflow. Of course, all signatories of the existing contracts need to agree to the upgrade workflow. You can only unilaterally upgrade data that you are in full control of. In the crypto currency world, you can consider all miners as signatories. Either they all agree on an upgrade or they hard fork, leading to two slightly different models of the same currency.

This sort of model upgrade process in DAML is described in detail here: https://github.com/digital-asset/ex-upgrade

Comment: Thanks a lot @bame, This really helps!